# OR Condtion with Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to migrate our JDBC code to Hibernate/JPA. So for now I was able to learn findAll(), findById(), delete() and save() and do them pretty well. But then I stumbled up a SQL query like this:

```
StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();

sqlQuery.append("SELECT *");
sqlQuery.append(" FROM " + DeviceAccessTable);
sqlQuery.append(" WHERE (DEVICENAME = ? OR DEVICENAME = 'ALL')");
sqlQuery.append(" AND (SERVICE = ? OR SERVICE = 'ALL')");
sqlQuery.append(" AND (VENDOR = ? OR VENDOR = 'ALL')");
sqlQuery.append(" AND CREDENTIAL_USE =? ");
sqlQuery.append(" AND PASSWORDTYPE =?;");

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery.toString());

preparedStatement.setString(1, deviceDetails.getName());
preparedStatement.setString(2, deviceDetails.getService());
preparedStatement.setString(3, deviceDetails.getVendor().toUpperCase());
preparedStatement.setString(4, use);
preparedStatement.setString(5, passwordType);

resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

I wrote it something like this:

```
deviceAccessCredKey.setCredentialUse("ALL");
deviceAccessCredKey.setPasswordType("LOCAL");
            
if (deviceConnectionDetails.getDeviceName() != null) {
    deviceAccessCredKey.setDeviceName(deviceConnectionDetails.getDeviceName());
} else {
    deviceAccessCredKey.setDeviceName("ALL");
}

if (deviceConnectionDetails.getService() != null) {
    deviceAccessCredKey.setService(deviceConnectionDetails.getService());
} else {
    deviceAccessCredKey.setService("ALL");
}

if (deviceConnectionDetails.getVendor() != null) {
    deviceAccessCredKey.setVendor(deviceConnectionDetails.getVendor());
} else {
    deviceAccessCredKey.setVendor("ALL");
}

Optional<DeviceAccessCreditals> optional = deviceAccessCredRepository.findById(deviceAccessCredKey);
```

My JPA classes are something like:

```
@Entity
public class DeviceAccessCreditals implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4561830468065539524L;

    @EmbeddedId
    DeviceAccessCredKey deviceAccessCredKey;

    @Column(name = "enablepassword", nullable = false)
    private String enablePassword;

    @Column(name = "lastupdate", nullable = false)
    private String lastUpdated;

    @Column(name = "updateuser", nullable = false)
    private String updateUser;

    @Column(name = "userid", nullable = false)
    private String userID;
    
.
.
.
}
```

and:

```
@Embeddable
public class DeviceAccessCredKey implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2858692808393518724L;

    @Column(name = "credential_use", nullable = false)
    private String credentialUse;

    @Column(name = "devicename", nullable = false)
    private String deviceName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "passwordtype", nullable = false)
    private String passwordType;

    @Column(name = "service", nullable = false)
    private String service;

    @Column(name = "vendor", nullable = false)
    private String vendor;

    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

My Repository class is like:

```
public interface DeviceAccessCredentialsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DeviceAccessCreditals, DeviceAccessCredKey> {

}
```

The above code returns nothing from the table. Is my approach okay? Not sure how to do and `OR` statement in this situation, any ideas would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be good to post your DeviceAccessCredRepository.java as well.
Have you tried if [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) works? ([Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details))

```
public interface DeviceAccessCredRepository extends JpaRepository<DeviceAccessCreditals, DeviceAccessCredKey>{
  
  //Query Method
  DeviceAccessCreditals findByDeviceAccessCredKey_DeviceNameIn(List<String> deviceNames);

}
```

You can also implement [native or JPQL queries](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) by defining them in your Repository like:

```
//JPQL (Foo here is your model and not the table)
@Query("SELECT foo FROM Foo WHERE bar = ?1")
List<Foo>findByBar(String bar);

//Native (Foo here is the db table)
@Query(
  value = "SELECT foo FROM Foo WHERE bar = ?1", 
  nativeQuery = true)
  List<Foo>findByBar(String bar);
```

Comment: Apologies, I thought since it was just a plain interface with nothing special in it. I didn't put it in. But I have edited the main question with it now.

Comment: If you need a custom query you have to define it in your repository in one of the 3 ways I mentioned. The findById method that is already implemented by spring, can be used just like you did. If you have no results, you should check that your DeviceAccessCredKey is correctly defined in java and matches with your DB.

Comment: Make sure to set the following configuration on your application.properties so you can see the actual query that is running: 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true    
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was looking at `@Query` my only problem was how to pass the parameters to the query, but i learned it and looking at a few examples online. Thanks.